# Android Studio SuppressLint "ClickableViewAccessibility" not working

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

In some cases I want to disable scroll on my ScrollView.
To do that I'm using `.setOnTouchListener` and return `true` in `onTouch`.

3.0 studio gives me lint warning that I should override `performClick` method also and I don't wanna do that.

When I hit `alt+enter` it gives me an option to supress this warning, it adds `@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")` to my method.

Unfortunately, this is not working - I still see that warning.
I also tried different combinations of `//noinspection`, but no luck.

How can I supress this lint warning?

Comment: "3.0 studio gives me lint warning that I should override performClick method also and I don't wanna do that." Can someone explain to me why this is suggested by Studio?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have noticed the same that neither the annotation

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
```

nor the inline suppression

```
//noinspection AndroidLintClickableViewAccessibility
```

work reliably. The latter does suppress the warning when working in Android Studio IDE, but does not suppress it when running Lint as Gradle task.

So far the only suppression method that works both in Android Studio and with Lint Gradle task is to combine the inline suppression

```
//noinspection AndroidLintClickableViewAccessibility
someView.setOnTouchListener(...)
```

with the Lint configuration file (that works on file granularity), e.g. in `build.gradle`:

```
lintOptions {
    lintConfig file("lint.xml")
}
```

and in `lint.xml`:

```
<lint>
    <issue id="ClickableViewAccessibility">
        <ignore path="**/TheClassToSuppressTheWarningIn.java"/>
    </issue>
</lint>
```

For what it's worth, there's [an issue reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65125896) and it should be fixed in Android Studio 3.1.

---

Update 2018-03-28: Yes, it's fixed in Android Studio 3.1.

Comment: Wow, great, thanks a lot! One question - where did you took AndroidLintClickableViewAccessibility from? ) I tried to search it somewhere in sources, but ho help.

Comment: Cannot remember where I learned it originally but generally `//noinspection AndroidLintXxx` suppresses `Xxx` lint check on the following line of code, making it the most localized (and therefore most preferred) method of suppression.

Comment: Thanks, `//noinspection AndroidLintClickableViewAccessibility` removed annoying warning.