# Why is Android studio is showing yellow highlighted in this code?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Helloe everyone!
I am curious to know why android studio is showing yellow highlighted in this portion of code.

I am using this touch listener on EditTextView because I want to hide something when this EditTextView is clicked/

> > snippet of code

[image]

Comment: If you hover over the code, I expect Android Studio will tell you why it's highlighted.

Comment: If you click on ! in triangle (in top right corner of the editor), it will show you all the warnings that highlights the code

Comment: @SauravRao , help me with this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74834819/how-to-implement-onclicklistener-inside-dialogbox-which-is-inside-fragment-in-an

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codes automatically get highlighted if there's  any warning or suggestions for a code block . In this case , the Android studio suggests to use a lambda function.

To see the suggestion ,

1. Hover over the code block
2. Right click > Show context Action
3. Alt + Enter

Comment: Yes, did that and it added "@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")"

Comment: For that suppression try this > https://stackoverflow.com/a/47134490/13651898

Comment: Will you help me answering this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74834819/how-to-implement-onclicklistener-inside-dialogbox-which-is-inside-fragment-in-an